# Javascript - Using condition with object and array

Tags: javascript

I receive a `data` value from a API, and I want to make a condition to deal with it. Sometimes it can comes as an array or object. I will use a simple example.

```
data = [1,2,3] // These values come from API
data.map(i => i++)
```

The problem is: Sometimes `data` can also comes as this

```
    data = {
       arr: [1,2,3]
    }
    // It evals an error in .map, because now "data" is an object
```

I know that I can solve it making something like this:

```
if(Array.isArray(data))
 data.map(i => i++);
else
 data.arr.map(i => i++);
```

But my code is not just a one line `.map`. Is there a way to make this simple condition without copying and paste code?

**Thanks!**

Comment: Easiest and maintainable way would be to have a helper function `function getData( data ) { return Array.isArray( data ) ? data : data.arr }` and then use that everywhere `getData( data ).map( i => i++ )`

Comment: @drinchev you should put your solution as an answer, I think your solution is better for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple OR (`||`) operator is pretty idiomatic JavaScript:

```
(data.arr || data).map(i => ++i);
```

If the `data.arr` property is defined, that will be mapped, otherwise `data` itself will be mapped.

---

Complete snippet:
<sub>Note: the post-increment operator would have no effect, so I replaced it with a pre-increment.</sub>

```js
let data, result;

data = [1, 2, 3];

result = (data.arr || data).map(i => ++i);
console.log(result);

data = {
  arr: [1, 2, 3]
}

result = (data.arr || data).map(i => ++i);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The most clean solution to my problem. Thank you :) !!

Answer (score 3):

You can for example assign the array reference to another variable and use it in the rest of your code, like this:

```
let arr = Array.isArray(data) ? data : data.arr;
arr.map(i => i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator.

```
Array.isArray(data)
? data.map(i => i++);
:  data.arr.map(i => i++);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [destruction](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment) es6 , not sure its a good idea but you can achieve your functionality in single line. ;)

```
let { arr=data } = data;
arr.map(i => i++)
```

if arr key is not found in **data** then it will assign default data array.
Cheers

Comment: Nice, this is a great use of destructing assignment!

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it like this**

You can use the ternary  operator and assign the value as array directly to temp if it is an Array and if not than you assign using the property like `input.arr` which is an Array.

So once the value is in form of array than you can use the single map statement so you need not to repeat your map statement.

```js
let data = [1,2,3];
let data1 = {
       arr: [1,2,3]
    }
    
    
function handle(input){
  let temp = Array.isArray(input) ? input : input.arr
  return temp.map(i => i++);
}

console.log(handle(data))
console.log(handle(data1))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wish to use an `if` or a `ternary` operator you can use `Object.values(data).flat()` to convert your `data` into:

`[1, 2, 3]`

This will essentially not modify your array and leave it be, however, it will compress your data object into an array form.

See working examples below:

*Data form 1 (obj)*:

```js
const data = {arr: [1, 2, 3]};
const res = Object.values(data).flat().map(i => ++i);
console.log(res);
```

*Data form 2 (array)*:

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3];
const res = Object.values(data).flat().map(i => ++i);
console.log(res);
```

Do note, however, `Object.values` does not guarantee order, and thus your array *may* lose its order. Moreover, if you plan to use this in production `.flat()` isn't yet supported across all browsers and instead, you may consider looking at a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#reduce_and_concat) option